# What's wrong with my implementation of OpenCV's warpAffine?

Tags: python, opencv

For some reason, I need to re-implement OpenCV's `warpAffine` using GPU and I **only need to translate the input image without rotation**. That is, my 2×3  transformation matrix has the form:

```
[[ 1, 0, x_shift],
 [ 0, 1, y_shift]
```

which would make the implementation simpler.

Then I implemented the prototype using Python to verify the algorithm:

```py
# Bilinear Interpolation:
# for a source image, sample a value indexed by (y, x) even if x, y are fractionals.
def sample(img, x: float, y: float):
    h, w = img.shape

    left = math.floor(x)
    top = math.floor(y)
    right = left + 1
    bottom = top + 1

    # top left corner
    if (0 <= left < w) and (0 <= top < h):
        a = img[top, left]
    else:
        a = 0

    # top right corner
    if (0 <= right < w) and (0 <= top < h):
        b = img[top, right]
    else:
        b = 0

    # bottom left corner
    if (0 <= left < w) and (0 <= bottom < h):
        c = img[bottom, left]
    else:
        c = 0

    # bottom right corner
    if (0 <= right < w) and (0 <= bottom < h):
        d = img[bottom, right]
    else:
        d = 0

    # linear interpolation of top two points
    top_interleaved = (right - x) * a + (x - left) * b

    # linear interpolation of bottom two points
    bottom_interleaved = (right - x) * c + (x - left) * d

    # linear interpolation of top and bottom points
    return (bottom - y) * top_interleaved + (y - top) * bottom_interleaved


def warpAffine(img, shift_x: float, shift_y: float):
    output = np.empty_like(img)

    h, w = img.shape
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            output[y, x] = sample(img, x - shift_x, y - shift_y)

    return output
```

And test it with:

```py
a = np.arange(1, 5, dtype=np.float32).reshape(2, 2)
# a = [[1, 2],
#      [3, 4]]

shift_x = 0.1
shift_y = 0.1

warpAffine(a, shift_x, shift_y)
```

It outputs:

```py
array([[0.81, 1.71],
       [2.52, 3.7 ]], dtype=float32)
```

It looks good but is a little different from OpenCV's `warpAffine`:

```py
affine_arr = np.array([[1, 0, shift_x], [0, 1, shift_y]], dtype=np.float32)
affine_img = cv.warpAffine(
    a,
    affine_arr,
    (a.shape[1], a.shape[0]),
    flags=cv.INTER_LINEAR,
    borderMode=cv.BORDER_CONSTANT,
    borderValue=0,
)
```

The `affined_img` is:

```py
array([[0.82, 1.73],
       [2.55, 3.72]], dtype=float32)
```

I don't know what went wrong. I tried to read [OpenCV's source code of `warpAffine`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/abda7630737fa8307efc88169d3525d3d2005898/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp#L2622) but it's too hard to read. I hope someone who's familiar with OpenCV's `warpAffine` can tell me what's my implementation's issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small differences happen because OpenCV uses a 5-bit lookup table and all integer arithmetic for its linear interpolation.

The result will not be *identical* but close by some measure deemed acceptable.

if your shift is a multiple of 1/32, the results should agree a lot better.